# 2D game engine for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, 2d

I worked on a few projects in Java and now, I want to get a step forward with game programming.

I'm not looking for a 3d game engine like Unity, but for a simple 2d game engine for eclipse, that generates the basic codes for a game (like sprite-definition, animations, scripts, movements or collision...)

I looked for a coding tutorial for 2d games but making a game only by hand would take waaaaaay too long without a little eclipse add-on!

So I wanted to ask you guys if you know any simple game engines for Eclipse?
I already worked with the Game Maker and Unity...

Comment: Try libgdx (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/). Its the best Game Engine that let you get started very quickly and is fairly simple if you understand how a Game Loop works. You can create a game that will run on Desktop for now, but later make it also work on Android and Html 5 Browser when you are ready. The reason I recommend Libgdx is because of its availability of good documentation, articles and its community. And for the other reason that you are already familiar with Java. **Libgdx has a UI based app project setup utility that will create an Eclipse project and all you have to do is to i